# MySQL NEW keyword

Tags: mysql, mysql5, mysql-5.0

I have what seems like a basic question, but I have been unable to find the answer.  Does the NEW keyword in MySQL refer to what the row will look like after the given action is performed or does it only refer to actual values used in the query?  For example:

Say I have a table sample with columns A int(6), B varchar(10), and C varchar(10).  This table has one row (1, "hello", "world"). If I then perform an update:

```
UPDATE TABLE sample
SET C = "bob"
WHERE A = 1;
```

If I had an after update trigger I would expect the value of NEW.C to be "bob" but will the value of NEW.B be "hello" or null?

Comment: No. `NEW` refers to the data which is incoming with the query (what you specify in `VALUES` for `INSERT` or `SET` for `UPDATE`, leaving non-specified values in they current state). `OLD`, on the other hand, refers to current record state (before modification)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If I am updating one table from another and if the trigger is after an insert or update do I even need the NEW or OLD keyword then?  Could I just do something like:

`UPDATE sample2 u
join sample s
on u.A = s.A
SET u.B = s.B
WHERE u.A = s.A;`

@AlmaDo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value of `NEW.C` would be `hello`. You can also get the previous value (before the update) by using `OLD`.